# OpenCV Skeleton center line; I need only the centerline!! How to remove all other branches

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

This is the code that I have implemented to obtain the centerline for the below-attached image. But I need only the centerline and remove all other branches and noise.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

binary_fish = cv2.imread('/content/data/fish12-masked.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Step 1: Preprocessing
# Apply erosion and dilation to the binary fish image
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
binary_fish = cv2.erode(binary_fish, kernel, iterations=1)
binary_fish = cv2.dilate(binary_fish, kernel, iterations=1)

# Step 2: Threshold to create a binary image
_, binary_fish = cv2.threshold(binary_fish, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Step 3: Skeletonize the binary fish image
skeleton = morphology.skeletonize(binary_fish > 0)

# Step 4: Find the centerline from the skeleton
skeleton = skeleton.astype(np.uint8) * 255

# Find the contours of the skeleton
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(skeleton, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Extract the largest contour (assuming it's the centerline)
centerline = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Create a blank canvas
height, width = binary_fish.shape
centerline_image = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)

# Draw the centerline on the canvas
cv2.drawContours(centerline_image, [centerline], -1, 255, 1)

# Overlay the centerline on the original fish image
original_fish = cv2.imread('/content/data/fish12-masked.jpg')
overlay_image = original_fish.copy()
overlay_image[centerline_image > 0] = [0, 0, 255]  # Red color

# Display or save the image with the centerline
cv2_imshow(overlay_image)
```

[obtained center line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSrcO.jpg)

Comment: How do you define the center line? What property can you name that is satisfied by the portion you want to keep and not satisfied by the portion you want to erase?

Comment: Find all vertices using a properly shaped morphology kernels (variety of line junctions). Break the vertices by drawing white there. Then find all contours and keep only the longest.

Comment: @fmw42, can you help me with that? I tried but, it's not accurate. Thank you!

Comment: @repo_twei. It is not as simple as I thought.  I think one has to break the vertices. Then get the contours. Then traverse the contours from one end to the other, keeping only the next segment that has the most similar direction to the previous section. Once you have removed all the side segments, you can use morphology to connect them again.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Center-Line meaning I need the skeleton of the fish from head to tail. So that I can utilize the obtained line to calculate its length.

Comment: Ok, but how do you define “head” and “tail”? And I don’t mean by understanding what a fish is and knowing what a fish’s head looks like. I mean mathematically, from the outline and the skeleton. Note that the two most distant end points of the skeleton are often not the two relevant end points. This is really not an easy thing to define, unless you put in lots of additional information about what you’re imaging, how it can deform and curve, what shape variations exist, etc.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, what I actually did was to computer the 2 farthest points on the contour, which gives me 2 points( from head to tail) using the distance formula. Based on these 2 endpoints, I applied the OpenCV Skeleton package, to get the skeleton of the masked image that I have provided.